# Opengl Rotation

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a sequence of items and I want to rotate them on the x and y axis in place as a whole. That is, I want all of my items to count as one item and for that one item to rotate in place. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

In general, determine a reference point, perhaps the center of gravity of all of the items.  Call this point (x,y).  Then

- Translate the items by (-x,-y)
- Rotate them all
- Translate them back by (x, y)

You will want to precompute the composite transform, of course, but this is the basic idea.

Note that by "items" we really just mean all of the polygons in your set of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the objects after translating them into their places. In short, it comes down to the order of matrix transformations: you want to do rotation * translation, not the other way around.